# List all outgoing edges using GraphQL in DGraph

Tags: graphql, dgraph

I have freebase dump in a distributed environment in Dgraph.

I also have 4.5 Million node addresses and want to iterate over the edges of those nodes.

I am using GraphQL. Can you point me in the right direction as to how I can (enumerate?) over the edges and reach the neighbor nodes?

Note: I don't know the edge types.

Is this relevant? http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of predicates in GraphQL+-, you can use `_predicate_` keyword. If you want to expand the predicates, you can use `expand` function. Keyword `_all_` can be especially useful for you.

Take a look at [Expand Predicates section](https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#expand-predicates) of Dgraph documentation 
 for more details and examples.